# How to obtain an unified expression for the symbolic integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbolic

When I use the Mathematica to obtain the integral of the symbolic expression, the output result seems not to be applied for all the cases. For example I use the code

```
Integrate[Cos[m Pi x] Cos[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1},
Assumptions -> m \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers]
```

to calculate the integral $$\int\cos (m\pi x)\cos (n \pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The output is 
$$\frac{m \sin (\pi  m) \cos (\pi  n)-n \cos (\pi  m) \sin (\pi  n)}{\pi  m^2-\pi  n^2}$$

I define a function with respect to the variables $m$ and $n$

```
f[m_, n_] := (
  m Cos[n \[Pi]] Sin[m \[Pi]] - n Cos[m \[Pi]] Sin[n \[Pi]])/(
  m^2 \[Pi] - n^2 \[Pi]);
```

Obviously, the function $f(m,n)$ is only applicable for the cases $m\neq n$. Some assumptions are made during the calculation by Mathematica. Now I want to obatin the unified expressions for the integral, for example, The result can be a conditional expression.

Comment: In fact the function `f(m,n)` is applicable for the cases `m=n`, if one takes the limit `n->m` instead of assignment. Try enhance the definition: `f[m_, m_]:=Limit[f[m, n], n -> m]`.

Comment: @Mher Thanks for your comments. It works for this example. The example shown in this post is a minimal work example. I want to apply the function(The function in my real work is much complex than this example) to a large list and I found that the `Limit` is very time-consuming. Are there any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the folowing defition

```
f[m_, n_] = 
  PiecewiseExpand[
    Which[m == n, 
    Integrate[Cos[m Pi x] Cos[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {m \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers && 
   m == n}], m != n, 
  Integrate[Cos[m Pi x] Cos[n Pi x], {x, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {m \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers && 
   m != n}]]]

{f[1, 2],f[1,1]}

(*    {0, 1/2}    *)
```